# Prevent Javascript from manipulating browser history

Tags: firefox, browser, javascript

I noticed that some sites manipulate the browser history using javascript.
This sometimes leads to some annoying things like prevents you from using 'back' to return to a previous site.
Or dangerous things, like the back button can now lead you to a different, possibly dangerous website.

This feature seems a bit useless and dangerous and it is described in the mozilla developer website:
[Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history)

Is there a way to disable this in the browser? (I can completely disable javascript, but this breaks a lot of sites)

I'm mainly looking for a solution for Firefox, but a solution for any other browser would be welcome.

Comment: I am also affected by this. My tab history was replaced with a referral link. This is plain bad - JS shouldn't control history.

Comment: While not quite an answer, I have found sort of a workaround: I typically open links in a new tab instead of the same one. That way, the history is copied.

Comment: @danuker See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open the [about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) page in Firefox
- Search for "pushstate"
- Double-click "browser.history.allowPushState"

Note that not all browser history manipulation is bad. It can be used for valid reasons.

Comment: this setting does not appear to exist in firefox 116.0.3 on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can always do what I do. I always open links in a new tab window. That preserves my history in the current tab, yet opens a new tab with the content. They can manipulate the history all they want. When I'm ready to go back, I just close the tab and return to the previous tab.